# problem converting Java class with getters and setters to Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I use Intellij to convert the Java code to Kotlin.

My Java class:

```
public class Test {

    private String mName;

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.mName = name.trim();
    }

}
```

Converted Kotlin class:

```
class Test {
    var name: String? = null
        private set

    fun setName(name: String) {
        this.name = name.trim { it <= ' ' }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to preserve the property name as "mName" ?

==========================

PS: Very appreciate guides from @Sam.

Manually editing the kotlin code after conversion seems not a good option for me, as there are many such fields.  I feel in my case, a stand-alone project (not a public library), it's easier to refacter the getter and setter names in Jave before converting the code to Kotlin, like:

```
public class Test {
    private String mName;

    public String getMName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setMName(String name) {
        this.mName = name.trim();
    }
}
```

Then the converted kotlin code becomes:

```
class Test {
    var mName: String? = null
        private set

    fun setMName(name: String) {
        mName = name.trim { it <= ' ' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: The name associates with a DB field.  I want to make converted Kotlin code be compatible with Java code using the same DB.

Answer (score 2):

The converted Kotlin class can actually be further optimised, like this:

```kotlin
class Test {
    var name: String? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value?.trim()
        }
}
```

This is making use of an [implicit backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields). If you wanted to make it more explicit, and name the backing field yourself, you can do that too using a [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties):

```kotlin
class Test {
    private var mName: String? = null

    var name: String?
        get() = mName
        set(value) {
            mName = value?.trim()
        }
}
```

The docs mention that on the JVM, "access to private properties with default getters and setters is optimized to avoid function call overhead." In practice what that means is that getters and setters won't be generated for the `mName` property, so you'll just end up with a private field called `mName`. From Java's perspective, my second Kotlin example looks identical to the Java class in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am not clear from the links as to how to name the backing field explicitly.  Do I do it in Java before conversion?

Comment: I added a little more explanation to my answer. Because the `mName` property is private, Kotlin won't generate getters and setters for it, and will just turn it into a private field called `mName`, the same as in your Java class.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you explain how you generated the second kotlin code?

Comment: I just wrote it myself by hand, but you can achieve something similar using automated tools in IntelliJ by creating a `var name: String?` and then choosing "Introduce backing property" from the context actions (`Alt`+`Enter`) menu.

Comment: I don't think there's going to be an easy way to get IntelliJ's auto-conversion to produce exactly the Kotlin code you need without a bit of manual intervention unfortunately.

Comment: > The converted Kotlin class can actually be further optimised

Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-15214/